# how to make tab visible below the action bar only in phone and tablet

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am creating a tab pager in my app but the issue is in my phone tabs are visible below the actionbar and in tablet its aligned with the title bar.

but i want to show tabs below the actionbar in phone and tablet both.

in my phone it shows as follows

[image]

in my tablet it show as follows

[image]

here is the action bar code

```
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // i tried with a true also but same result
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false); 

    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActionBar tab is deprecated from api 21. use one of below approach to fix your issue and be up to date:-)

1)[FragmentTabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html)

2)[TabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html)

3)[PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)

4)[SlidingTabsBasic](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html)

if you use any of the above approach your issue will be solved